# Why am I getting errors in ext-all-debug.js in lines 4236 - 4242?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I've developed a PHP framework that generates **ExtJS code** in the form of an application.

This involves building the full **ExtJS object literal** on the first call, e.g.:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    menuItemStart = new Ext.Panel({
        id: 'panelStart',
        title: 'Start',
        html: 'This is the start menu item.',
        cls:'menuItem'
    });
    ...
```

and then navigation in the application consists of **event handlers** which load PHP files via AJAX that output ExtJS code, and then execute this code with this function:

```
function loadViewViaAjax(url, paramTargetRegion) {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: url,
        success: function(objServerResponse) {
            var responseText = objServerResponse.responseText;
            var scripts, scriptsFinder=/<script[^>]*>([\s\S]+)<\/script>/gi;
            while(scripts=scriptsFinder.exec(responseText)) {
                eval(scripts[1]);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This works well. However, I now have this situation where when a page is loaded from **PHP** instead of via a **triggered ExtJS event handler**, I get errors that are varied but all come from one block of code in the `ext-all-debug.js` file, namely in line `4236` and line `4242`:

[image]

**Has anyone experienced anything similar or know what could be causing this?**

## Addendum

Yes @ChrisR, here is an error I can reproduce on my machine:

[image]

It says it is getting the error in the fourth line of this code, but if I click on it, it takes me to line `4242` shown above in the ExtJS library code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    clearExtjsComponent(targetRegion);
    var panel_form = new Ext.FormPanel({
        labelWidth: 100,
        frame:true,
        style: 'margin: 10px',
        title: 'Test Product (TEST PAGE 2)',
        bodyStyle:'padding:5px 5px 0',
        width: 500,
        defaultType: 'textfield',

        items: [{
                fieldLabel: 'ID',
                value: "111",
                name: 'id',
                width: 370,
                hidden: false,
                style: 'text-align: right',
                name: 'id',
                width: 50,
                hidden: false,
            },{
                fieldLabel: 'Product',
                value: "Paper",
                xtype: 'displayfield',
                name: 'product',
                width: 370,
                hidden: false,
            },{
                fieldLabel: 'Label',
                value: "none",
                name: 'product3',
                width: 370,
                hidden: false,
            },{
                fieldLabel: 'Label',
                value: "first line\<br/>second line\<br/>third line",
                xtype: 'displayfield',
                height: 100,
                xtype: 'displayfield',
                name: 'product4',
                width: 370,
                hidden: false,
            }
        ],

        buttons: [{
                text: 'Save',
                handler: function() {
                    if(panel_form.getForm().isValid()){
                        panel_form.getForm().getEl().dom.action = 'backend/application/help/test';
                        panel_form.getForm().getEl().dom.method = 'POST';
                        panel_form.getForm().submit({
                            success : function(form, action) {
                    replace_region_with_uri_content('backend/modules');
                            }
                        })
                    } else {
                        Ext.Msg.minWidth = 360;
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Invalid Form', 'Some fields are invalid, please correct.');
                    }
                }
            },{
                text: 'Cancel',
                handler: function(){
                    replace_region_with_uri_content('backend/modules');
                }
            }]
    });
    replaceComponentContent(targetRegion, panel_form);

    hideComponent(regionHelp);
</script>
```

Comment: can you add (one of) the actual errors you get?

Comment: yes, I posted the error above that I can reproduce on my machine

Comment: That error is located in the Ext.util.JSON.decode methods ... are you somewhere trying to decode the scripts you are loading as json or where does the decode method fit in your loading algorithms?

Comment: in this example I'm not doing anything with JSON at the Javascript level so I assume this is being called internally, but these errors "missing } in XML expression" and another is just "syntax error" in a line where there is no syntax error, says to me that code is being added inside the javascript structure which simply causes the sytanctical structure of the object literal to become invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Is this on IE?  If so, all the trailing commas in your code may be the issue (they certainly are *an* issue).  Also, lots of duplicate configs in your first item.  Try running [JSLint](http://jslint.com/) on your code from time to time to catch stuff like that.